# Position in onBindViewHolder in adapter always returns last item

Tags: android, android-studio

The goal is when I click on an item in the gridview, it should open another activity showing the details of the item selected. However, the value being passed to the new activity (through the .putExtra) is always the last item in the arraylist regardless of which item I tap on. This is inside the adapter class btw. Thank you :)

The code can be seen below

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final listHolder newsHolder, final int position) {

        currentNews = newsList.get(position);
        listHolder.ivArt.setImageResource(currentNews.getArt());
        newsHolder.ivArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(viewGroup.getContext(), ViewNewsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list, (Parcelable) list);
                viewGroup.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: make your `ViewHolder` implements `OnClickListener` and use one of "position" getter method inside `onClick` method

Comment: why you are passing parameters as final ?!!

Answer (score 1):

You get such a strange behaviour because of the `OnClickListener()` set in `onBindViewHolder` method. Add `setOnClickListener()` to view inside `onCreateViewHolder()` and create `new View.OnClickListener()` inside adapter.

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        ...
    }

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int viewPosition = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
            ...
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Don´t make the position final on your onBindViewHolder, because if you delete any items or add an item the ViewHolder will still have the reference of the old positions, instead consider using: holder.getAdapterPosition()

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't declare position as final.
2. currentNews = newsList.get(position); 
   add this inside the onClick Method